# Tableview cells repeating containing collection view Swift

Tags: swift-language, reading-code, firebase

### I am having trouble presenting my tableview cells containing a Collectionview correctly. I want to display a different animal in each section based on the firebase data. My problem is about every 4 cells the first 4 cells repeat(See images below). I have separate models for each animal and I am configuring each cell with each animals information. Everything is loading fine except in the information being reused. For example:

### Row 1 : chicken

### **Displays chickens

### Row 2: Cows

### **Displays Cows

### Row 3: Bees

### **Displays Bees

### Row 4: Goats

### **Displays Goats

### Row 5: Ducks

### **Displays Chickens again, Then ducks

### Row 6: Rabbits

### **Displays Cows again, Then rabbits

This happens mostly when I scroll down so im guessing it has something to do with the dequeing of the cells. I put the indexpath.section to print and on section 4 I get 0? Im so confused! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: MyCollectionTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionTableViewCell
    switch indexPath.section {
        
    case 0:
        cell.chickenConfigure(with: chickenModels)
            return cell
    case 1:
        cell.cowConfigure(with: cowModels)
        return cell

    case 2:
        cell.beeConfigure(with: beeModels)
        return cell

    case 3:
        cell.donkeyConfigure(with: donkeyModels)
        return cell

    case 4:
        cell.duckConfigure(with: duckModels)
        return cell

    case 5:
        cell.goatConfigure(with: goatModels)
        return cell

    case 6:
        cell.horseConfigure(with: horseModels)
        return cell

    case 7:
        cell.pigConfigure(with: pigModels)
        return cell

    case 8:
        cell.rabbitConfigure(with: rabbitModels)
        return cell

        
    case 9:
        cell.sheepConfigure(with: sheepModels)
        
        
        return cell
        
    default:
        let cell = table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: MyCollectionTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionTableViewCell
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "Nil")
        return cell
    }
    
}
```

And in my Collectionview it looks like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    if indexPath.section == 0{
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: MyCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
        if !chickenModels.isEmpty{
        cell.chickenConfigure(with: chickenModels[indexPath.row])
        return cell
        }
        else{
            cell.myImageView.image = nil
            return cell
        }
    }
    if indexPath.section == 1 {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: MyCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
        if !cowModels.isEmpty {
        cell.cowConfigure(with: cowModels[indexPath.row])
        
        return cell
        }
        else{
            cell.isHidden = true
            return cell
        }
    }
    if indexPath.section == 2 {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: MyCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
        if !beeModels.isEmpty {
        cell.beeConfigure(with: beeModels[indexPath.row])
        
        return cell
        }
        else{
            cell.isHidden = true
            return cell
        }
    }
    if indexPath.section == 3 {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: MyCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
        if !donkeyModels.isEmpty {
        cell.donkeyConfigure(with: donkeyModels[indexPath.row])
        
        return cell
        }
        else{
            cell.isHidden = true
            return cell
        }
    }
    if indexPath.section == 4 {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: MyCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
        if !duckModels.isEmpty {
        cell.duckConfigure(with: duckModels[indexPath.row])
        
        return cell
        }
        else{
            print("In the ELSE")
            cell.unusedConfigure(with: unusedModels[indexPath.row])
            return cell
        }
    }
    if indexPath.section == 5 {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: MyCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
        if !goatModels.isEmpty {
        cell.goatConfigure(with: goatModels[indexPath.row])
        
        return cell
        }
        else{
            cell.isHidden = true
            return cell
        }
    }
    if indexPath.section == 6 {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: MyCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
        if !horseModels.isEmpty {
        cell.horseConfigure(with: horseModels[indexPath.row])
        
        return cell
        }
        else{
            cell.isHidden = true
            return cell
        }
    }
    if indexPath.section == 7 {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: MyCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
        if !pigModels.isEmpty {
        cell.pigConfigure(with: pigModels[indexPath.row])
        
        return cell
        }
        else{
            cell.isHidden = true
            return cell
        }
    }
    if indexPath.section == 8 {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: MyCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
        if !rabbitModels.isEmpty {
        cell.rabbitConfigure(with: rabbitModels[indexPath.row])
        
        return cell
        }
        else{
            cell.isHidden = true
            return cell
        }
    }
    if indexPath.section == 9 {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: MyCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
        if !sheepModels.isEmpty {
        cell.sheepConfigure(with: sheepModels[indexPath.row])
        
        return cell
        }
        else{
            cell.isHidden = true
            return cell
        }
    }
    else {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: MyCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
        
        cell.duckConfigure(with: duckModels[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer! After reading through similar questions I came to a great solution that entailed clearing the model array that the cell was using before it was reused by using prepareForReuse(). Answer is in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45247616/not-using-reusable-cell-in-uitableview-with-collectionview-in-each-cell